# How do you escape or remove double quotes in the output if using strip_tags function

Tags: php, twitter

Trying to add Twitter meta tags. I have this snippet to manage the Twitter description. I am creating meta tags to support both the summary and product Twitter cards, hence the if statement

This works mostly fine. The correct descriptions display for the summary and the product cards. The issue is that while the HTML tags are stripped out of the products_description text as I need/expect, any product descriptions that contain double quotes will prevent the Twitter product type cards from properly being validated or even picked up by Twitter.

What do I need to add so that the double quotes are either removed or escaped?

```
<?php 
if (in_array($current_page_base, array('product_info', 'document_general_info', 'document_product_info', 'product_info_noproduct', 'product_music_info'))) {?>
<meta name="twitter:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags($zcdTwitterProductCard->info['products_description'])?>" />
<?php }else{?> 
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Your summary card description would go here" />
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Disregard this question.. Figured out a solution.. (still could use some confirmation of this thought) replaced "strip_tags" with "htmlspecialchars" (and yes I know that I could alternately use "htmlentities")

Answer (score 1):

Use `htmlspecialchars(stringToEscape, ENT_QUOTES)` to remove the double quotes.

http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

Comment: Yes, thanks.. I answered my own question right after I posted it indicating that's what I planned to do.. lol


I know that I could alternately use "htmlentities". So, perhaps can you address why I should use "htmlspecialchars" instead of "htmlentities" or does it matter?? This will help others who find this question (and my follow-up response to my own question) so they can understand why they should precede this way.